# how to increase width for submenu in CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I would like to change the width of the sub-menu on my website from CSS (attached image):

[My WEBSITE](http://acumulatorionline.gomag.ro/)

PIN/CODE: 1234

[Attached image with the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPrEF.jpg)

I tried to change from:

> .drop-list.clearfix.w60

class, but without luck.

Comment: Without any mention of what framework you are using, this is almost impossible to solve. All i can say is that ```.menu-dd ul {float: left; width: auto!important;}``` overrides  ```.w60``` class due to 'important'.

Comment: @Lalalena This is a custom framework, called [GoMAG](https://www.gomag.ro)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't speak the language. I suggest reading the framework's documentation, since the width calculation seems to be done in javascript. There might be classes to add to your elements to prevent this default behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
/*submenu fix*/
.main-header .drop-list .col {
  width: 376px !important;
}
```

and thanks Lalalena !